# Sort has_many relation in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

my model is

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :jobs
end
```

in controller i want get client with sorted jobs.
If i do (without ordering)

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id], :include => {:jobs => :status})
```

It is all ok. But if i add ordering:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id], :include => {:jobs => :status}, :order => 'job.level DESC')
```

// :order is dynamicly set (not in this example) - i know about :order in has_many.

the result is only 3 rows (for every job.level one). I logged the sql query and executed it and result is ok, but in app i have only these 3 rows.
What is the right way to sort jobs? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what i originally wanted, but it works, so this is answer

```
@jobs = @client.jobs.find(:all, :order => sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the order directly in the model instead of the controller

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :order => 'level DESC'
end
```

OR

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :order => 'level DESC'
end
```

Also, what data type is the level in the Jobs model? If you could post your logs for the sql queries that would be helpful as well.  Also, have you tried

```
:order => 'jobs.level'
```

instead of the singular job.level used in the code you posted?

Comment: But if ordering depends on url parameter, then specifying :order in the model doesnt't help.

SQL: SELECT ... FROM "client" LEFT OUTER JOIN "job" ON "job"."clientid" = "client"."clientid" LEFT OUTER JOIN "status" ON "status"."jobstatus" = "job"."jobstatus" WHERE "client"."clientid" = 2 AND "client"."clientid" IN (2) ORDER BY job.level